# Object doesn't support property or method 'data'

Tags: javascript, jquery

The issue I am having, is when I am trying to update a text element through the data key, it gives me "Object doesn't support property or method 'data'" error.

I have used this before on **MealNameError** function to do the same thing, and it worked but when I try it on **MealItemError** function I am having issues.

```
function MealNameError(databaseMealName) {
    var $this = $("#ContentPlaceHolder1_AddMealName");
    $('#' + $this.data('describeby')).text('"' + databaseMealName + '" 
    already exists').show();
 }

function MealItemError(duplicateItems) {
    $('#addItemDropdownList_1, #addItemDropdownList_2, #addItemDropdownList_3, #addItemDropdownList_4, #addItemDropdownList_5')
    .each(function() {
        for (var i = 0; i < duplicateItems.length; i++) {
            if (parseInt($(this).val()) === duplicateItems[i]) {
                $('#' + this.data('describeby')).text('Only one of same Item').show(); //This line is throwing the error
            }
        }           
    });
 }
```

I would normally put data('key',value'), but the value is dynamic depending on how many food items they add. Any ideas to what am I doing different between those two problems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap `this`  with `$()` to treat it like an jQuery element `$(this).data('describeby')`.

In your `MealNameError` function your have it wrapped already.

Answer (score 1):

**You have two ways to solve that problem:**

- Wrap the `this` context with jQuery function `$`

```
$('#' + $(this).data('describeby'))
```

- Use the built-in `dataset` attribute.

```
$('#' + this.dataset.describeby)
```